# JSON Parsed Data Not Showing

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview, android-arrayadapter

I thought I parsed my data in the right manner but I am unable to have it display. Could you please let me know where my error is?

I have various things that are being passed but I only want each item on the list view to display certain attributes and the following is my code. I'm just having a blank main activity show up.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();

ListAdapter adapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String result = "";

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject productsMade = json.getJSONObject(i);

            int PRODUCT_ID = productsMade.getInt("productId");
            int STYLE_ID = productsMade.getInt("styleId");
            String BRAND_NAME = productsMade.getString("brandName");
            String PRODUCT_NAME = productsMade.getString("productName");
            int COLOR_ID = productsMade.getInt("colorId"); 
            int ORIGINAL_PRICE = productsMade.getInt("originalPrice");
            int PERCENT_OFF = productsMade.getInt("percentOff");
            int PRICE = productsMade.getInt("price");
            String PRODUCT_URL = productsMade.getString("productUrl");
            String IMAGE_URL = productsMade.getString("imageUrl");

            productList.add(new Product(PRODUCT_ID, STYLE_ID, BRAND_NAME, PRODUCT_NAME, 
                    COLOR_ID, ORIGINAL_PRICE, PERCENT_OFF, PRICE, PRODUCT_URL, IMAGE_URL));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
    }


    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    adapter = new ListAdapter();

    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>{

    ListAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, productList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_values, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(productList.get(position));
        return (convertView);
    }

}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textBrandName = null;
    public TextView textProductName = null;
    public TextView textOriginalPrice = null;


    ViewHolder(View row) {
        textBrandName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.brand_name);
        textProductName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        textOriginalPrice = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.original_price);
    }

    void populateFrom(Product r) {
        textBrandName.setText(r.getBrandName());
        textProductName.setText(r.getProductName());
        textOriginalPrice.setText(r.getOriginalPrice());
    }
    }

}
```

Where am I going wrong that I just see a blank page?

My list_value.xml file looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/brand_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<TextView 
    android:id = "@+id/original_price"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

While my main_activity.xml just has a list view within in.

Comment: You should probably remove your Zappos API key from the code you post here. It's technically private information.

Comment: Just for advise, use String stringEntity= EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); and JSONArray json = new JSONArray(stringEntity);

Answer (score 0):

you must got **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException** because you try connect to network on main thread in `onCreate()` method. since android version +3.0 you can not connect to internet on `UI` thread you must use `Handlers` or `AsyncTask` for connecting to the internet, best way is **AsyncTask** class.

for see the sample and  documentation see following link.

[Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

you can see following article for more info:

[Android Background Processing with Handlers and AsyncTask and Loaders - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line on ListAdapter

```
@Overide
public int getCount()
{
return productList.size();
}
```

Comment: don't need this, in `arrayAdapter`, super in `constructor` do this, `getCount` and `getItem` must be override on BaseAdapter

Comment: is there any exception report on log ?